# Cannot stat , No such file or directory linux

Tags: linux, shell, mv

Ive looked over some other questions similar to this but none of the solutions worked for me. I've got two directories `Teacher` and `Employee`. I've got a file in the `Teacher` directory called `Emp7.tar.gz` and i want to move it into the `Employee` directory. I'm using a shell script to move it but i keep getting the same error. The code im using to move it is

```
#:/bin.bash
mv Emp7.tar.gz Employee/
```

I know its probably simple but im just getting used to linux so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! If your working directory is `Teacher`, then your command should be:

```
mv Emp7.tar.gz ../Employee/
```

If your working directory is one above `Teacher`, then your command should be:

```
mv Teacher/Emp7.tar.gz Employee/
```

If your working directory is `Employee`, then your command should be:

```
mv ../Teacher/Emp7.tar.gz .
```

Answer (score -1):

```
mv Emp7.tar.gz ../Employee
```

You need to specify the relative path to the Employee directory.

As you're in the Teacher directory, you need to get up once